# After updating Android SKD to API 31 on release build Gson().fromJson doesn't work

Tags: android, gson, release, minify

After updating Android project SKD from API 30 to API 31

```
Gson().toJson(...)
Gson().fromJson(...)
```

Gson copy doesn't work with minifyEnabled = true

```
Full code of extension 
inline fun <reified T> T.deepCopy(): T {
    val json = Gson().toJson(this)
    return Gson().fromJson(json, T::class.java)
}
```

After **deepCopy()** object becomes null

Comment: Have you added the provided proguard rules (https://github.com/google/gson/blob/master/examples/android-proguard-example/proguard.cfg)?

Comment: Yes, but unfortunately it didn't help me. What really helped me in produar-rules.pro -keep class test.org.module.model.response ** { *; } or other words omit all classes